# Haskell: need to understand signature of Functor

Tags: haskell

Can some body explain me the signature of Functor.

```
Prelude> :info Functor
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (<$) :: a -> f b -> f a
```

I don't understand what `*` means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` is the syntax used by Haskell for [**kinds**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Kind)

In this case it means that `f` is higher-kinded (think functions on the type level)

Here `f` is taking one type (the first `*`) and is producing another type (the second `*`)

you can basically forget all this here and just read it as:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (<$) :: a -> f b -> f a
```

but it's a nice documentation IMO and there are quite a few classes that are more complicated and the *kind-signature* is really helpful - for example:

```
class MonadTrans (t :: (* -> *) -> * -> *) where
  lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
        -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Class'
```

Here `t` takes a type-constructor itself (the Monad) together with another type and produces a type again.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that while there are kinds other than `*` (and combinations of `->` and `*`), you generally don't have to worry about them for general programming.

Comment: And the usual terminology complaint: "type constructor" has a specific meaning which is not appropriate here. `Int`, `Bool`, `Maybe`, `Either`, and `StateT` are all type constructors of various kinds, some of which are not even higher kinds; `Either e` is *not* a type constructor but has the appropriate kind to be a `Functor`. Think by analogy to the term level: `True` and `False` are term constructors, even though their types have no arrows in them, whereas `(,) 3` is not a term constructor even though it has an arrow in its type.

Comment: @DanielWagner what is the correct name? And where can I find a good reference - is type-operator better?

Comment: @Carsten The Report is the canonical resource; the section on [the syntax of types](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-650004.1.2) gives a good rundown of terminology. You can say that types whose kind have an arrow in them are _higher-kinded_. In the other direction, I have heard people use the term _concrete type_ to refer to types of kind `*`.