# How to create Functor definition for Either type

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, trying to understand Functor. I took following code from Data.Either module (Replaced data Either with Either1). I just updated by removing 'Either1 a' and replaced it with 'Either1' (instance Functor **Either1** where).

```
data Either1 a b = Left1 a | Right1 b

instance Functor Either1 where
    fmap f (Left1 x) = Left1 x
    fmap f (Right1 y) = Right1 (f y)
```

When i try to load above snippet, I am getting following error.

```
Prelude> :load Sample.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Sample.hs, interpreted )

Sample.hs:3:18:
    Expecting one more argument to ‘Either1’
    The first argument of ‘Functor’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
      but ‘Either1’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Functor Either1’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

My question is, Why should I put "Either1 a" while defining fmap function, why can't 'Either1" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36790797/1126841), functors require a type of kind `* -> *`. `Either1` has kind `* -> * -> *`; you need to partially apply `Either1` to get a type of the proper kind.

```
> :k Either1
Either1 :: * -> * -> *
> :k Either1 Int
Either1 Int :: * -> *
```

When defining the `Functor` instance, it doesn't really matter to the functor what the first type is, so you can just specify an unconstrained type variable instead of a concrete type like `Int`.

Answer (score 3):

When you implement Functor, you need a type that accepts a single type argument. `Either1` accepts two type arguments, `a` and `b`, so your definition should look like this:

```haskell
instance Functor (Either1 a) where
    fmap f (Left1 x) = Left1 x
    fmap f (Right1 y) = Right1 (f y)
```

(I also fixed a compilation error in the `Left1` case; you were missing the `f` parameter)

The online book, [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass) has a great introduction on Functors which talks in depth about the partial application of `Either` described here.

Answer (score 2):

You're completely right – it's a bit strange to have the functor instance work only on the right argument of `Either`.

Indeed `Either` is not just a functor, it's a [bifunctor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#t:Bifunctor):

```
instance Bifunctor Either where
    bimap f _ (Left a) = Left (f a)
    bimap _ g (Right b) = Right (g b)
```

However, you may always consider a bifunctor to be also a “monofunctor” on one of the two functor-arguments. Because of how type-argument currying works, you have to choose the second one in Haskell. Essentially, you're working with “half of the bifunctor”! For instance,

```
type EitherStr = Either String  -- the `Right` argument is left open as the functor argument!

instance Functor EitherStr where
  fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
  fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
```

But of course this works for *any* given type, not just `String`. So you can just make the instance generic over the first argument:

```
∀ a . instance Functor (Either a) where
  fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
  fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
```

Well now, the `∀ a .` before an instance is just implicit in Haskell. If you want to make it explicit this is the correct syntax:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}
instance ∀ a . Functor (Either a) where
  fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
  fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
```

Comment: Aaaaaand just to clarify, the actual syntax for the last example is `instance forall a. Functor (Either a) where`

Comment: Interesting, since when is `∀` actually legal in instance declarations? I'm pretty sure it used not to be.

Comment: Since I remember, but I'm relatively new to Haskell :). Anyway, [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46a9b4be4fd21cab) (the undecidable bit isn't really the part of it).

Comment: Typo (I think): you omitted the first argument to the `Left x` cases.

Comment: I think the thing that isn't allowed is something like `instance Functor (forall a. Either a) where ...` (which might be useful in some situations, if it were allowed).

Answer (score 1):

In [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), when you first meet term 'kind' you can find that you don't need to have thorough undestanding of this concept to move on, but seems to me that you should spend some extra time to pick the idea, because further material will become more and more tricky without a good comprehension of this issue.

As mentioned above, Either has kind `* -> * -> *`, but Functor expects something with kind `* -> *` - you may think of this as a type, parametrized with another (concrete) type - actually - type constructor. For example Int has kind `*`, `Maybe Int` has kind `*`, but `Maybe` has kind `* -> *` - so the type constructor `Maybe` is a good candidate to be used in Functor. How can we achive the same kind with `Either a b` - again, use partial application to fix the first parameter and you'll get `Either a` - construction which is parametrized by one concrete type `b`. Here you should see, why first parameter is not changed in `fmap` function - couse it`s fixed.

I apologize for some possible duplication of the first answer, but I remeber myself spending too much time and trying to undestand `kinds` - so I urgently needed somebody to give me simple explanation.

Good luck learning!